# Populate value in p:autocomplete when the forms loads

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG autocomplete in my Angular 2 application and I want to populate it with a value when the form loads. I have a user profile form which has a autocomplete field and initially the user selects a value and submits the forms. Now when the user visits this page again the autocomplete field should be the populated with the value that the user has selected before. I am not sure how this can be achieved using p:autocomplete. The following is my code:

html:

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="userInfo" inputStyleClass="form-control" size="90" [minLength]="1" [suggestions]="dataSource"
value="displayText" (focus)="onLostFocus($event.target.value)" (blur)="onItemBlur($event.target.value)" field="text" (completeMethod)="getData($event)"
(onSelect)="onItemSelected($event)" (change)="onTextChanged($event.target.value)"></p-autoComplete>
```

Comment: Is the "userInfo" set in on your component's loading ?

Comment: No it is set only when the value is selected/changed.

Comment: So initialize it :)

Comment: Yes. But this component is used inside another component. So in the main component the web service is called and I am not sure how I could initialize it.Is there any working example that I can follow.

Comment: @Karbos538  I also have similar issue  I am using  <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]= "selectedItems[i]" inside a table with ngFor and index i ..when I set selectedItems[i] it does not autocomplete any preset value but if I set selectedItems[0 or 1, or 2 etc] it shows the same value  in all columns. Why it is not considering variable i  from *ngFor="let row of invoiceItemsData; let i = index"?  If I pass the same i elsewhere i.e in function then I am able to read Its value correctly .

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let row of invoiceItemsData; let i = index"  >
<td># {{i}}</td>
<td> <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selectedItem[i]" [immutable]="false" [suggestions]="filteredItems" (completeMethod)="filterItemByName($event)" (onSelect)="handleItemDropdownClick(i)"   name="it_{{row.serialNo}}" field="nameOfItem"  [size]="30" placeholder="Item"  [minLength]="1"></p-autoComplete>  </td>

</tr>

Comment: initialised value of 
 selectedItem=[{'serialNo': this.serialNo,'nameOfItem':'krishna','hsn':'','quantity':'','ratePerItem':'15','discount':'','taxRate':''},{'serialNo': this.serialNo,'nameOfItem':'hare','hsn':'','quantity':'','ratePerItem':'15','discount':'','taxRate':''},{'serialNo': this.serialNo,'nameOfItem':'Radha','hsn':'','quantity':'','ratePerItem':'15','discount':'','taxRate':''}];